# I want to use data from a Future inside a ChangeNotifier Provider and a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I can't figure out how to get the data from the myProvider before I call the getWalletItems(). Should I do 2 seperate providers??
My goal here is just to get all these items from a Future<List<Wallet'>> and return them into a listview that is able to have each item be selectable with a checkbox which will then pass on all the selected items to a different page. They will not be rebuilt there so I don't think I need another model but if I do just let me know. Here is my code for the ChangeNotifier:

```
class WalletModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Wallet> _wallet = [];
  List<Wallet> get wallet => _wallet;

  set wallet(List<Wallet> newValue) {
    _wallet = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  myProvider() {
    loadValue();
  }

  Future<void> loadValue() async {
    wallet = await WalletApi.getWalletItems();
  }

  UnmodifiableListView<Wallet> get allWalletItems =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_wallet);
  UnmodifiableListView<Wallet> get incompleteTasks =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_wallet.where((_wallet) => !_wallet.isSelected));
  UnmodifiableListView<Wallet> get completedTasks =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_wallet.where((_wallet) => _wallet.isSelected));

  void toggleWallet(Wallet wallet) {
    final walletIndex = _wallet.indexOf(wallet);
    _wallet[walletIndex].toggleSelected();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is the checkbox to select

```
Checkbox(
                value: wallet.isSelected,
                onChanged: (bool? checked) {
                  Provider.of<WalletModel>(context, listen: false)
                      .toggleWallet(wallet);
                },
              ),
```

Here is the listview and if I need to post anyother code just let me know because I'm quite lost on what to do.

```
class WalletList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Wallet> wallets;

  WalletList({required this.wallets});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: getWalletListItems(),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getWalletListItems() {
    return wallets
        .map((walletItem) => WalletListItem(wallet: walletItem))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make myProvider() a future and then use below code for WalletList Widget

1. before build runs for WalletList we want to get the items from the provider so we have used didChangedDependencies() as it runs before build and can be converted to future.
2. when the list is got we use the list that was set by above the make the UI

Note : Consumer changes its state whenever notifyListener() is called in Provider.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WalletList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WalletListState createState() => _WalletListState();
}

class _WalletListState extends State<WalletList> {
  bool _isInit = true;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    //boolean used to run the set list fucntion only once
    if (_isInit) {
      //this will save the incoming data to list before build runs
      await Provider.of<WalletModel>(context, listen: false).myProvider();
      _isInit = false;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<WalletModel>(builder: (context, providerInstance, _) {
      return ListView(
        children: providerInstance
            .wallet
            .map<Widget>((walletItem) => WalletListItem(wallet: walletItem))
            .toList(),
      );
    });
  }

  // List<Widget> getWalletListItems() {
  //   return Provider.of<WalletModel>(context, listen: false)
  //       .wallet
  //       .map((walletItem) => WalletListItem(wallet: walletItem))
  //       .toList();
  // }
}
```